# Replacement LCD EDID

Tags: lcd, edid

Laptop had B154EW08-V0 display which broke and was replaced with LTN154P1-L02. Now image flooded by white or black vertical pixel-wide alternate stripes. Old and new LCD EDID was dumped. Writing old EDID to new LCD leads to splitting screen in 2/3 (strips stays). Change PIXEL CLOCK, VBLANK, HBLANK to defaults gives no result.

Where to dig next?

Here is what i have:

**Old LCD**

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 06 af 74 80 00 00 00 00    ........??t?....
10: 01 11 01 03 80 21 15 78 0a 1c f5 97 58 50 8e 27    ?????!?x????XP?'
20: 27 50 54 00 00 00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01    'PT...??????????
30: 01 01 01 01 01 01 12 1b 00 87 50 20 10 30 30 20    ????????.?P ?00 
40: 36 00 4b cf 10 00 00 18 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00    6.K??..?...?....
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 fe 00 41    ......... ...?.A
60: 55 4f 0a 20 00 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fe    UO? .       ...?
70: 00 42 31 35 34 45 57 30 38 20 56 30 20 0a 00 39    .B154EW08 V0 ?.9
80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
```

**New LCD**

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 4c a3 00 00 00 00 00 00    ........L?......
10: 00 0d 01 03 80 21 15 78 0a 87 f5 94 57 4f 8c 27    .????!?x????WO?'
20: 27 50 54 00 00 00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 01    'PT...??????????
30: 01 01 01 01 01 01 44 2f 90 c4 60 1a 0f 40 18 58    ??????D/??`??@?X
40: 13 00 4b cf 10 00 00 19 00 00 00 0f 00 00 00 00    ?.K??..?...?....
50: 00 00 00 00 00 3c d2 02 64 01 00 00 00 fe 00 53    .....<??d?...?.S
60: 41 4d 53 55 4e 47 0a 20 20 20 20 20 00 00 00 fe    AMSUNG?     ...?
70: 00 4c 54 4e 31 35 34 50 31 2d 4c 30 32 0a 00 fe    .LTN154P1-L02?.?
80: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
90: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
a0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
b0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
c0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
d0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff    ................
```

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to check my new LCD LVDS specs. Bought 2-channel instead of single-channel. Solved by replacing to correct one.